# How can I make a 10 second countdown timer before a download button link appears for blogspot in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, button

On a download page, I would like to have it so that when the page loads, a 10 second timer automatically starts. On the page, I would like some text to say something like "You can begin your download in 10 seconds..." Then, after the time is up a download button appears for people to click on and start their download.

How can I do this, and what code do I use to include it into a page?

Comment: yes you can do it.  post the code you have try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, you could use a `setInterval` and then when time is expired, show a button like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<input id="button" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" value="DOWNLOAD" />

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date().setSeconds(new Date().getSeconds() + 10);
document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = "hidden";

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You can begin your download in " + seconds +" seconds...";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text and show button to download
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Click DOWNLOAD button";
    document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}, 1000);

function startDownload() {
   // here start the download
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where I;ll add my link

Comment: @MaryamRashid you could use button onclick event.

Comment: i want to add an external link to drive. where I'll add my drive link

Comment: that link should appears after countdown like button?

Comment: yes. I want that link to open when some one clicks the button

Comment: @MaryamRashid instead of a button you could use `<input id="button" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" value="DOWNLOAD" />` and modify `'https://google.com'` with your link. See my answer modified.

Comment: No problem :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the download part itself has to be worked out with a server, but assuming you have the direct URL of the file, you can set it to an a tag with a download attribute, then for the countdown just use setTimeout for one second set s time, incrementing a variable each time and if it's greater than 9 then call .click() on the a tag to download it

Assuming there is already Div in the page with I'd "counter",

```
var a=document. createElement ("a")
a.href="direct URL of file goes here"
a.download="file name plus the extension.txt"

var currentSecond=0
function second () {
   setTimeout(function () {
        currentSecond++
        counter. innerHTML= (10-currentSecond)+" seconds to go before download starts automatically"
        if(currentSecond > 9)
            a.click()
         else second ()
    }, 1000)
}

second ()
```

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't the same as `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```html
   <div>
      <div id="countdown"></div>
      <a href="file" id="download" style="display: none"><button type="button">Download</button></a>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var time = 10;
     var interval = setInterval(() => {
        time--;
        if (time <= 0) {
          document.getElementById("countdown").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("download").style.display = "block";
          clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("countdown").innerText = "You can begin your download in" + time +  "seconds..."
        }
     }, 1000);

   </script>
```

Comment: But can you please add the word download like a button. Just like a simple button